# Call constructors and methods from dynamically created classes

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, reflection.emit, mono.cecil

I'm creating dynamic assemblies with Cecil. How can I call its constructors or methods when emitting opcodes?

```
class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(new SomeClass().SomeMethod());
    }
}

class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeMethod() { return 0; }
}
```

As you can see I need 2 instructions for the WriteLine methods - `OpCodes.Newobj` and `OpCodes.Call`:

```
var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.CreateAssembly ( ... );
...
var mainMethod = new MethodDefinition( ... );
var ilProcessor = mainMethod.Body.GetILProcessor();
...
ilProcessor.Create(
    OpCodes.Newobj,
    assembly.MainModule.ImportReference(/* typeof("SomeClass") */
        .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)));

ilProcessor.Create(
    OpCodes.Call,
    assembly.MainModule.ImportReference(/* typeof("SomeClass") */
        .GetMethod("SomeMethod", Type.EmptyTypes)));
```

What can I do to mimic `typeof("SomeClass")` to call `GetConstructor` and `GetMethod`?

Comment: Once you've created the dynamic type, do you not have access to a `TypeInfo`? (I usually use `TypeBuilder`  for this, and `TypeBuilder` lets you use `.CreateType()` to get a `TypeInfo` that you can use with `ILGenerator`, or you can pass in the `TypeBuilder` itself as it *is* a `TypeInfo` - just not a `RuntimeTypeInfo`)

Comment: @MarcGravell I'll try your suggestion with Cecil `TypeDefinition`, which is similar to Reflection.Emit `TypeBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create assembly:

```
var moduleName = "Test.exe";
var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.CreateAssembly(new AssemblyNameDefinition(moduleName, new Version(1, 0, new Random().Next(1000))), moduleName, ModuleKind.Console);
var module = assembly.MainModule;
```

Create first type:

```
TypeDefinition someClass;
MethodDefinition someMethod;
{
    someClass = new TypeDefinition("ConsoleDemo", "SomeClass", TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public, module.TypeSystem.Object);
    someMethod = new MethodDefinition("SomeMethod", MethodAttributes.Public, module.TypeSystem.Int32);
    someMethod.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0));
    someMethod.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ret));
    someClass.Methods.Add(someMethod);

    var someClassCtor = new MethodDefinition(".ctor", MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName, module.TypeSystem.Void);
    someClassCtor.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0));
    someClassCtor.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, objCtor));
    someClassCtor.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ret));
    someClass.Methods.Add(someClassCtor);

    module.Types.Add(someClass);
}
```

Now create main class:

```
var testClass = new TypeDefinition("ConsoleDemo", "Test", TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public, module.TypeSystem.Object);
var mainMethod = new MethodDefinition("Main", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, module.TypeSystem.Void);
mainMethod.Parameters.Add(new ParameterDefinition("args", ParameterAttributes.None, new ArrayType(module.TypeSystem.String)));
var writeLineMethod = typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(int) });
var importedMethod = module.Import(writeLineMethod);
mainMethod.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Newobj, someClass.GetConstructors().First()));
mainMethod.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, someMethod));
mainMethod.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, importedMethod));
mainMethod.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ret));
testClass.Methods.Add(mainMethod);

var mainClassCtor = new MethodDefinition(".ctor", MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName, module.TypeSystem.Void);
mainClassCtor.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0));
mainClassCtor.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, objCtor));
mainClassCtor.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ret));
testClass.Methods.Add(mainClassCtor);
module.Types.Add(testClass);
```

Don't forget to set entry point:

```
module.EntryPoint = mainMethod;
```

Now you can save it:

```
assembly.Write(moduleName);
```

After run it prints '0' to stdout just as expected